# jquery auto complete with key value pair search

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

i have a problem with the auto complete script,
the result required is when i type eg BG or BRIGHT GREEN to get result "BG"

```
    <?php

     $colours = 
                          [
                            'LG'=>'LIGHT GREEN',
                            'BG'=>'BRIGHT GREEN',
                            'DR'=>'DARK RED',
                            ];

    ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <form id="frm" method="post">
    <input id="color" type="text" >
    </form>
        <script>
        var colorObj =  <?php echo json_encode($colours); ?>;
        $("#color").autocomplete({
            source:colorObj,
            minLength: 2,
            select: function(event, ui) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $("#color").val(ui.item.label);
            }
        });
        </script>
```

Comment: convert  $colours  array into simple array

Comment: i tried like this var colorObj =  ["<?php echo  implode('","',$colours); ?>"];;                    but the search working  only when i type "BRIGHT GREEN"  not working when i type BG

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery autocomplete doesn't work with key value pair array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24970352/jquery-autocomplete-doesnt-work-with-key-value-pair-array)

Comment: @SarvanKumar irrelevant answer [jQuery autocomplete doesn't work with key value pair array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24970352/jquery-autocomplete-doesnt-work-with-key-value-pair-array) . the correct one is [Filter Jquery AutoComplete by multiple values of an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15267912/filter-jquery-autocomplete-by-multiple-values-of-an-array-of-objects)